# GDALRasterizeLayers with ALL_TOUCHED and ATTRIBUTE option

Tags: c++, gdal

I'm using GDALRasterizeLayers to rasterize a river and lake network. When I'm using the ALL_TOUCHED option, every pixels are burn. But with the ATTRIBUTE option (to burn the id of each feature), some pixels of the river are missing. I try to use both option, but it gave me the same result as ATTRIBUTE.

```
vector<OGRLayer*> layers;
layers.push_back(rivieres_datasource->GetLayer(0));
layers.push_back(lacs_datasource->GetLayer(0));

char** options = nullptr;

options = CSLSetNameValue(options, "ALL_TOUCHED", "TRUE");
options = CSLSetNameValue(options, "ATTRIBUTE", "ID");

GDALRasterizeLayers(dst_dataset, 1, &band_list[0], 2, (OGRLayerH*)&layers[0], NULL, NULL, NULL, options, NULL, NULL);

CSLDestroy(options);
```

Is it possible to use both options ? Thanks.

(sorry for my bad English, I'm french canadian)

Comment: Both options should work. If some pixels of the river are not rasterised, it could be a bug. There [previously was one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31568/gdal-rasterizelayer-doesnt-burn-all-polygons-to-raster/31658#31658), but it was fixed by GDAL 1.9.0. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.10.0

Comment: I have create a demo with the files that I use. It create 3 files, ALL_TOUCHED.tif that have all the pixels. ATTRIBUTE.tif that have missing pixels and ALL_TOUCHED_AND_ATTRIBUTE.tif which is supposed to be ok, but it's not.

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=7ecad65b80cfe693&id=7ECAD65B80CFE693%2118543

Comment: Thanks to kyle from osgeo ! He found the solution, in fact, everything is working fine. It is a display issue with MapWindows. How can I mark this as solve ?